# Multiple CSS selector

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am trying to create a CSS style to an element based on radio button check status. The following is the HTML code.

```
    <div>
        <input class="assaf" id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" value="3" /> 
    </div>
    <label for="radio3">
        <span><span>
        </span></span>
        Option 3
    </label>
```

The problem is, I can NOT write a CSS style so label and its children style are set based on radio button status (checked or not).

Removing the first div, I can do something like this which works fine.

```
input.assaf[type=radio]:not(old):checked}  + label > span > span
```

But, I have a case that must have this div, I tried something like the following but it does not work!!

```
div > input.assaf[type=radio]:not(old):checked}  + label > span > span
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Cannot do it based on your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It doesn't work.

You cannot select the `parent` element from `child` element and then reach its `sibling` in `css`.

Instead, you can place the `label` element inside the div and use:

```
input.assaf[type=radio]:not(old):checked}  + label > span > span
```

the same as you mentioned.

If you necessarily need the `div` around the `radio input`. I would like to know why?

Comment: I would like to edit the style of existing radio buttons written in dojo. The system is huge and very complicated, so I am looking for a minimal change to do(CSS is recommended).

Comment: you can style it with `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors on the `input`.